# How do I delete an xml node by attribute value?

Tags: xml, coldfusion, nodes

I have an xml object in my coldfusion code that looks like this:

[image]

I would like to have the ability to delete a node based on the zip. For example - delete the node that has a zip of '22222'.

I know that I can loop through each node, check the zip, and once I find it execute `<cfset ArrayDeleteAt(xmlDoc.terminals.XmlChildren, currentIndex)>` to delete that node. But is there any more intuitive way to do this? Any built in coldfusion functions that avoid explicit looping?

Answer (score 1):

I would use [jSoup](http://jsoup.org) for this. It's really a HTML parser, but can still be used against XML.

Once you've parsed the XML, selecting and removing by attribute is as simple as...

```
.select('[zip=22222]').remove()
```

...but here is a complete example, using jSoup 1.7.2 (earlier versions may have a slightly different API):

```
<cfsavecontent variable="XmlText">
    <TERMINALS>
        <terminal location="some random location" terminal="25" zip="11111" />
        <terminal location="some other location" terminal="26" zip="22222" />
        <terminal location="some more location" terminal="22" zip="33333" />
    </TERMINALS>
</cfsavecontent>

<cfscript>
    jSoup = createObject('java','org.jsoup.Jsoup');
    Parser = createObject('java','org.jsoup.parser.Parser');

    Dom = jSoup.parse( XmlText , '' , Parser.xmlParser() );

    Dom.select('[zip=22222]').remove();

</cfscript>

<cfdump var=#Dom.outerHtml()# />
```

For that code to work, CF needs to know about the jSoup classes, so it needs to be able to see the JAR file, which can be achieved in four different ways:

**Option 1:**
Place the jSoup jar in CF's lib directory - e.g. `{cf10}/cfusion/webroot/WEB-INF/lib` or `{cf9}/webroot/WEB-INF/lib` - and restart CF. [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478575/how-to-install-java-class-for-coldfusion-10).

**Option 2:**
Place the jSoup jar in a local directory and setup [`This.JavaSettings` in Application.cfc](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSe61e35da8d318518-106e125d1353e804331-7ffe.html) - this feature was added in CF 10 and Railo 4.0

**Option 3:**
Place the jSoup jar in a local directory and use [JavaLoader](https://github.com/markmandel/JavaLoader) to load it (similar to above, but works with any version).

The two createObject lines above should then be replaced with:

```
jl = new javaloader.JavaLoader([expandPath('./jsoup-1.7.2.jar')]);
jSoup  = jl.create('org.jsoup.Jsoup');
Parser = jl.create('org.jsoup.parser.Parser');
```

(assuming jar file is in same directory as script)

**Option 4:**
For Railo and OpenBD, the above options will work, or you can simply reference the path to the JAR file as a third argument to the [createObject](http://railodocs.org/createObject) calls.

Comment: Ooh, didn't know Railo did that! Thanks for the tangential tip.

Comment: When I try your second option to load the jar file, I get an error `The directory or file ./lib/ specified in LOADPATHS does not exist` ...

Comment: I assume the directory does exist? Try expandPath? Might need a restart of CF too.

Comment: @PeterBoughton - I don't work with the server much - how would I check for the directory? I thought this was something built in to CF10?

Comment: The functionality is built in. The path you specify with JavaSettings is up to you to setup as required - you're specifying a `lib` directory at the same level as `Application.cfc` - does one exist (and contain the jsoup jar)?

Comment: No, there is no lib directory there - so I have to do your step 1) as well (download the jsoup jar and place it where can access it)?

Comment: Sorry, that's a bit confusing me calling them steps - they are three distinct options rather than steps - you can EITHER place the JAR in `C:/ColdFusion10/cfusion/lib` (then you don't need to change Application.cfc) and restart CF, _OR_ you can place it in `{webroot}/anydiryoulike` and refer to that directory with Application.cfc (using lib is a common convention, not a requirement for this option).

Comment: I just didn't understand that your second option also involved downloading the jar - I'll try that, thanks

Comment: Sorry, I'm now getting an error on the 3rd line of your cfscript - `The parse method was not found.`. In place of `XmlText` I put the variable that holds my xml string. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you dump the `jSoup` variable before that line what does it show? Also, make sure you're using the XML string, not the XML object.

Comment: It shows a jSoup object with methods. I am definitely using the xml string, I've tried dumping it as well.

Comment: I actually don't see a parse constructor with `(string, parser)`. Are you sure that's valid?

Comment: I just cut out the parser altogether and now it seems to work. I wish there was a simple built-in way to do this though... this kind of seems like overkill

Comment: It _was_ valid - not sure what version I tested that with, but it definitely worked. Checking the latest Javadocs I don't see one either - it now wants a baseUri also :/

Comment: The parser prevents certain tags being modified, e.g. if your XML had `link` tags, they wouldn't be treated as HTML link tags.

Comment: Can I just clarify that if I place jsoup in `{cf10}/cfusion/webroot/WEB-INF/lib` and restart the CF server, then I don't have to do anything in Application.cfc to tell CF to load the jar file?