# How to install custom Java class for ColdFusion 10

Tags: java, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

We have just deployed CF 10 onto some new servers.

I'm trying to [follow this process](https://web-beta.archive.org/web/20150320153052/http://www.bpurcell.org/blog/index.cfm?mode=entry&entry=1100), which we had working without any issues on CF8. However I'm not sure how things are structured in CF10.

Our directory path in CF 10 appears as:

```
Coldfusion10\
   cfusion
   jre
   ininstall
```

Do all the additional Java classes get installed into `jre`?

Answer (score 5):

The only difference in CF10 is there is an extra directory layer between the {install root} and {web root}. ie

```
          coldfusion8\wwwroot
          coldfusion10\cfusion\wwwroot
```

However, it does not change [the rules about class loading](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec14231-7fe5.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec14231-7fd3). Jars can be placed anywhere, as long as they are accessible to the CF service, and the directory is in CF class path, or the default jvm class path.

There are several directories in the default class path that CF checks automatically, such as  `{cf_webroot}\web-inf\lib`. The simplest option is to place them in that directory. Then CF will pick them up automatically, no need to muck with the class path settings. Just drop your jars in that folder, restart the CF service, and you are good to go.