# ColdFusion Class not found: CyberSource

Tags: java, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I built a new Windows 2012 R2 server and upgraded from ColdFusion 9 to ColdFusion 11. Now when trying to make a payment, I am getting a *"Class not found: CyberSource"* error.

What class file do I need and where do I put it? I think the proper class path is `<CfoldFusion11>\cfusion\bin\`. Does anyone have experience with this issue?

Comment: Voting to close as there are already a number of threads on how to load a third party jar. In short, \cfusion\bin\ is not part of the CF class path.  See [How to install java class for Coldfusion 10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478575/how-to-install-java-class-for-coldfusion-10/18479224) (applies to CF11 as well)* [The Definitive Guide to the ColdFusion Classpath](https://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2004/07/the_definitive.html) (dated, but still relevant).

Comment: [Dynamic class loader in CF10+](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSe61e35da8d318518-106e125d1353e804331-7ffe.html).